# cwebuser is undefined when function exists

Tags: yii

cwebuser.isShop is not defined when a function exists. Not understanding why. I've searched around and all i find is the same question, no answer?
What I am trying to do is to login from a module name shop but I get not defined. What else am I missing?

in my main module;

```
public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
    {
    if(Yii::app()->getModule('shop')->user->isShop)  
        Yii::app()->getModule('shop')->user->setReturnUrl('shop/default/login');  
        else  
return false;
}
```

In webuser:

```
function isShop(){
        if (!isset(Yii::app()->user->user))
            return false;
        $user = Yii::app()->user->user;
        return intval($user->user_role_id) == 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write

```
Yii::app()->getModule('shop')->user->isShop
```

you are trying to access a variable of the Object user called `isShop`. Two cases:

1. `isShop` is a variable
2. `isShop` is a Virtual variable

Yours is the second case. This means that `isShop` is the result of calling the function `getIsShop` of the Object user, but your function is named only `isShop`.

Two Solutions:

1. rename the function `isShop` to `getIsShop`
2. call directly the function in the main module using

`Yii::app()->getModule('shop')->user->isShop()`. **[see the round brackets]**